# Only the page number in the header, nothing else

Tags: page-numbering

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
 a4paper,
 twoside,
 inner=5cm,
 outer=2.5cm,
 top=2.5cm,
 bottom=2.5cm,
 headsep=0.5cm
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

I need page numbers to be at the outer corner -- `\pagestyle{headings}` accomplishes this perfectly, however, it also adds the name of the section, which I do not want in the header.

I tried:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

which puts the number in the correct position, however, also produces an underlining, and does not understand the page margins (i.e. the width of the header is not the same as the width of the text).

Is there a way to avoid using the `fancyhdr` package, and still get the hoped result? And if I must use the `fancyhdr` package, how do I get rid of the underlining and set the correct width?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` after the `\fancyhead` instruction.

Comment: gets rid of the underlining, but the width of the header is still messed up (sorry, was editing the question about the width while you posted this answer)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this problem can be avoided simply with

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
```

Probelm solved.